# Rotation of a frame reference with axis z lying on normal n

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, 3d, rotations

I am creating a rotation matrix capable of converting the reference system $A=(x_a, y_a, z_a)$ into a second reference system $B=(x_b, y_b, z_b)$ where the $x_b$ and $y_b$ axes lie in a plane with normal $n$ and the $z_b$ axis is parallel to the normal $n$.

I am using the following formula in order to convert a $P_A=$ point to a $P_B$ point:

$$P_B=
P_A
\pmatrix{
{n_y\over\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2}}&
{-n_x\over\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2}}&
0\\
{n_xn_z\over\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2}}&
{n_yn_z\over\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2}}&
-\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2}\\
n_x&
n_y&
n_z
}=
\pmatrix{
p_x*{n_y\over\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2}} + p_y*{-n_x\over\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2}} + p_z * 0\\
p_x*{n_xn_z\over\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2}} + p_y*{n_yn_z\over\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2}} + p_z * -\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2}\\
p_x*n_x + p_y*n_y + p_z * n_z\\
}$$

however, trying this formula with a javascript code I get the following result (in red the transformed $x$ axis, in green the transformed $y$ axis, in blue the transformed $z$ axis and in yellow the normal $n$ to the gray plane below):

[image]

Does the rotation matrix seem correct to you?

Comment: It doesn't. A rotation matrix around the $z$-axis looks always like
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\cos\alpha &-\sin\alpha&0\\\sin\alpha&\cos\alpha&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\alpha$ is the counter clockwise rotation angle.

Comment: Thanks! however, to have the z axis parallel to the vector n, don't I have to perform at least 2 rotations (eg the first on the x axis and the second on the y axis)?

Comment: You wrote "... the x and y axes lie in a plane with normal n and the z axis lies along the normal itself". To me that means that $n$ and $z$-axis are parallel and stay parallel. If I am missing something then please rewrite the question to give full clarity of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: My fault, I have now explained better the problem. I want to go from a frame reference $A$ to a frame reference $B$ where the $z$ axis is parallel to the normal $n$

Answer (score 1):

The original coordinate frame is specified as follows

$ p = R q $

where $p$ is the world coordinates and $q$ is the coordinates with respect to the axes of your initial reference frame.  These axes have unit vectors that are the three columns of the $3 \times 3$ matrix $R$, where the third column is your vector $n$.  From here

$q = R^T p $

If you rotate the axes about $n$, then the new axes will be given by

$ R' = R_z(\theta) $

where

$R_z(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta) && - \sin(\theta) && 0 \\ \sin(\theta) && \cos(\theta) && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Hence if the new coordinates of $q$ are $q'$ then

$q = R' q'$

Thus $q' = R'^T q = R'^T R^T p $

And finally, $ p = R R' q' $

So the new axes are specified by the matrix $R R'$

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I think I have to perform at least 2 rotations to make sure that the $z$ axis is parallel to the vector $n$ (I just edited the question to make it more comprehensive). Also, how can I get the angle from the vector $n$?

Comment: I don't think you need to perform two rotations.  What you want is the direction of the axes after you rotate the axes about $n$, and the formula I gave does just that.